# JS если modal.show - то определенный div скрываем

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите, как скрыть определенный div=myblock2, если открыли модальное mymodal

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal mymodal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="myblock1 my-2 p-2 bg-danger">myblock1</div>
<div class="myblock1 my-2 p-2 bg-warning">myblock1</div>
```

Спасибо

Comment: кто вам мешает добавить обработчик на кнопку открытия модалки, и скрыть в нем что надо? Либо для модалки добавить событие открытия, и там скрыть? Если обратно надо показывать  при закрытии окна, то лучше через события модалки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишу "на коленке", но вероятно поможет.

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  $('.myblock2').hide()
})

$('#exampleModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
  $('.myblock2').show()
})
```

Почитайте : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events

Comment: нет, не работает

Comment: да, ное если модалку закрыть, то блок на место не появляется

Comment: есть, спасибо, работает !

Comment: если полностью меняете ответ, то лучше публикуйте новым ответом.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#exampleModal.show+.myblock1+.myblock1 {display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal mymodal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="myblock1 my-2 p-2 bg-danger">myblock1</div>
<div class="myblock1 my-2 p-2 bg-warning">myblock1</div>
```

Comment: верстка изменится, и все сломается.

Comment: @teran Да всегда можно нормально сверстать, нормально называя нужные и опорные для css блоки. Если нормально все делать, верстка ломаться не будет. А вот конкретно в этом случае (я специально верстку html не трогал) по другому сделать это правило и не получится.